# Does the type of preamplifier used for a piezoelectric sensor change its physical resonant frequency?

Tags: amplifier, circuit-design, resonance, piezo, preamp

Two common amplifier circuits used for piezoelectric sensors are voltage amplifiers and charge amplifiers (pictured respectively).
[image: Charge Amplifier Circuit]
[image: Voltage Amplifier Circuit]

With the charge amplifier, the sensor is shorted but this is not the case with a voltage amplifier. Does this effect the physical properties of the sensor?

Answer (score 3):

**Yes** it does effect the stiffness and thus also the resonant frequency of the sensor.

Liu, et al. in [1] show that for an closed circuit stiffness of \$Y_\text{open}\$, the short circuit stiffness \$Y_\text{closed}\$ is given by
$$Y_\text{short} = (1-k^2)Y_\text{short}$$
where \$k\$ is the electromechanical coupling factor. From this they compute the relationship of resonant frequencies:

$$\frac{f_\text{open}}{f_\text{closed}} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{1-k^2}}$$

As \$k\$ gets closer to \$1\$, the voltage amplifier can have significantly more usable bandwidth than the charge mode configuration.

> \$k\$ values quoted in ceramic suppliers' specifications typically are theoretical maximum values. At low input frequencies, a typical piezoelectric ceramic can convert **30 - 75%** of the energy delivered to it in one form into the other form, depending on the formulation of the ceramic and the directions of the forces involved.

[Piezoelectric Constants  from American Piezo](https://www.americanpiezo.com/knowledge-center/piezo-theory/piezoelectric-constants.html)

[1] *Liu, Weiqun & Feng, Zhihua & Liu, R & Zhang, J. (2008). The influence of preamplifiers on the piezoelectric sensor's dynamic property. The Review of scientific instruments. 78. 125107. 10.1063/1.2825404.*